RuntimeError: Illegal cast in Kotlin Multiplatform with Decompose and Koin on Web/Wasm target
I'm trying to run a Kotlin Multiplatform project on the Web/Wasm target.
Koin version: 3.6.0-wasm-alpha2.
An error occurs when invoking a factory method to create the Decompose rootComponent.
It works fine with a factory instance added manually or by Kodein DI. It also works fine on other targets(Android, Desktop).
val rootComponentFactory: RootComponent.Factory by koin.inject()
// error occurs when I add this line at runtime
val rootComponent: RootComponent = rootComponentFactory(DefaultComponentContext(lifecycle))

When the app loads in the browser, I get uncaught runtime errors:
illegal cast
RuntimeError: illegal cast
    at <DecomposeQuickGuide:composeApp>.main (http://localhost:8080/composeApp.wasm:wasm-function[74448]:0x67167a)
    at <DecomposeQuickGuide:composeApp>.kotlin.wasm.internal.mainCallsWrapper (http://localhost:8080/composeApp.wasm:wasm-function[74466]:0x675d21)
    at <DecomposeQuickGuide:composeApp>._initialize (http://localhost:8080/composeApp.wasm:wasm-function[74467]:0x675d2d)
    at instantiate (webpack-internal:///./kotlin/composeApp.uninstantiated.mjs:4470:21)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///./kotlin/composeApp.mjs:17:18)

The composeApp.wasm file.

How does this lead to an illegal cast, and how can I fix it?

It's hard to say without the actual casting error saying what were the expected and actual classes. It's possible that something is wrong with Koin DI, since it's not compile-time safe. You can try printing the outcome of koin.inject<RootComponent.Factory>(). Also, it's possible that you bumped into a compiler bug.

I agree, Koin Wasm is still in alpha, so this issue might be fixed later. I printed: println("Test injection: ${rootComponentFactory} | ${koin.inject<RootComponent.Factory>()}"), and got: Test injection: Factory@946381247 | Lazy value not initialized yet..

@ArkadiiIvanov can confirm it's an issue with koin, as I'm not using decompose
